# How to configure Symfony Messenger to work with topic exchange?

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

We have a project that partially uses DDD. When changing / creating an entity, we throw an event inside the entity. Next, the Doctrine Event Subscriber takes all the events and forwards them to the EventBus.

Let's say we have a `MissionCreatedEvent` event. I want to make routing key `mission.event.created` for it and tie it into 2 queues: `new_mission_notification_to_part_time_employee` and `new_mission_area_notification_to_manager`.

This is what the config looks like:

```yaml
transports:
    async_new_mission_notification_to_part_time_employee:
        dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        options:
            exchange:
                name: mission
                type: topic
            queues:
                new_mission_notification_to_part_time_employee:
                    binding_keys: ['mission.event.created']
        retry_strategy:
            max_retries: 0

    async_new_mission_area_notification_to_manager:
        dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
        options:
            exchange:
                name: mission
                type: topic
            queues:
                new_mission_area_notification_to_manager:
                    binding_keys: ['mission.event.created']
        retry_strategy:
            max_retries: 0

routing:
    'App\Domain\Mission\Event\MissionCreatedEvent':
        - async_new_mission_notification_to_part_time_employee
        - async_new_mission_area_notification_to_manager
```

The problem is that Symfony Messenger first runs on transports and only then pushes the message into exchange. Since we have 2 transports, it turns out that the event with routing key `mission.event.created` is triggered twice. Because of this, my Message handlers run 2 times.

There is an option not to use routing key `mission.event.created`. But use similar  to `mission.cmd.notify_part_time_employee_about_new_mission`
and `mission.cmd.notify_manager_about_new_mission_in_area` for each transport with direct exchange.

This will help solve duplication problems, but I can’t use all the features that RabbitMQ gives me :(

Comment: You are binding mission.event.created queue to your both notifier, it's natural that it will queue 2 messages in same queue. You are also provided separate queues for specific task, so what features are missing if you are gonna use separate queues?

Comment: @MaulikParmar I have 2 handlers which are mapped to transports:

1. `SendNewMissionAreaNotificationToManager` for `async_new_mission_area_notification_to_manager` transport.

2. `SendNewMissionNotificationToPartTimeEmployeeHandler` for `async_new_mission_notification_to_part_time_employee` transport.

I used swarrot bundle on previous project. I could map each consumer for separated queue: queue A -> `AConsumer`,  B -> `BConsumer`. And then map queues to routing key `mission.event.created`.

I think it is not possible to do the same thing for Messenger Component.

Comment: As far as doc says, you can specify routing key in config while dispatching logic: [amqp-transport](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#amqp-transport) As long as rabbitmq is using amqp you can specify this config.